# Proving a general inequality

Tags: inequality

I would like to prove that

$$2^n (1 + (\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2)^p) \geq \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + |a_i|^p) $$

where $p \geq 2$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1, ..., n$. This is a generalization of $4\left(1+\left(a^2+b^2\right)^{p}\right) \geq\left(1+|a|^{p}\right)\left(1+|b|^{p}\right)$. I am almost sure the this case with $n = 2$ comes from the Peetre's inequality which states that for any real number $t$

$$\left(\frac{1+|x|^2}{1+|y|^2}\right)^t \leq 2^{|t|}\left(1+|x-y|^2\right)^{|t|}.$$

I tried with a couple of different numbers and it really seems to be valid.

Comment: Have you tried splitting it up by $ |a| \geq 1,| a| < 1$? For the first case, show that $ 1 +( \sum |a|)^p > \prod (1 + a^p)$ which seems true at least for integers $p$. For the second case, $ 2 > ( 1 + |a|^p)$.

Comment: I cannot split like this since I may have the case where $a_1 = 0.1$ and $a_2 = 2$ for example.

Comment: Why not? Have you tried writing it out? EG Something like $ 1+( \sum a^2)^p \geq 1+(\sum_{|a| \geq 1} a^2 )^p \geq \prod_{|a| \geq 1} ( 1 + |a|^p)$.   $\quad$ Also, can you include your attempts for the $ n = 2$ case?

Comment: With $n=3,$ $p=2,$ and $a_i = 10$ for all $i,$ the lhs is $2^3(1 + 300^2)=720\,008$ while the rhs is $(1+100)^3=1\,030\,301,$ which is *greater,* thereby disproving the inequality.  Things only get worse for you for larger $n$ or larger $p.$